# SwiftUI: Bind TextField to property of type Decimal in Xcode > 13 beta 2

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to bind a number to a `TextField`. For numbers of type Double, it works fine. However, if I use the type `Decimal`, the user input is discarded since *Xcode Version 13 beta 3 and above*.

#### Question

How can the following code example be adapted to work correctly with numbers of type Decimal (NSDecimalNumber) in current Xcode versions?

#### Versions

- Xcode: >= 13.0 beta 4
- iOS: >= 15.0

#### Recording

Video recording of a failed input.
**When the second input field loses focus, the newly entered data is not applied, but the original data is displayed again.** Therefore I suspect a problem with the data binding.

[image]

#### Example

Code example, which works for numbers of type Double but not for numbers of type Decimal.

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct DemoModel {
        var doubleQuantity: Double = 1.23 // This works.
        var decimalQuantity: Decimal = 5.34 // This does not work.
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @Binding var model: DemoModel
        
        private let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
            return formatter
        }()
        
        var body: some View {
            Form {
                // This works correctly.
                TextField(
                    "Input a number of type double…",
                    value: $model.doubleQuantity,
                    formatter: numberFormatter)
                
                // Does not work.
                // What needs to be changed to make this work?
                TextField(
                    "Input a number of type decimal…",
                    value: $model.decimalQuantity,
                    formatter: numberFormatter)
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView_PreviewWrapper()
        }
        
        struct ContentView_PreviewWrapper: View {
            @State(initialValue: DemoModel()) var model: DemoModel
            
            var body: some View {
                ContentView(model: $model)
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Full Xcode project on Github

https://github.com/brads-dev-dojo/SwiftUITextFieldWithDecimalValueTypeApp

Comment: This works on Version 13.0 beta (13A5155e) (Beta 2)

Comment: Hello @Asad,
I have added a video recording to the question that shows the problem. The change in the second text field is lost when the field loses focus or when you tap return. So I assume that the data binding is not working correctly.

Comment: [This is how it is for me](https://imgur.com/CuSTw67)

Comment: Can you show the part of the code from where you are calling ContentView?

Comment: Hello @Asad,
I created a [repository on Github](https://github.com/brads-dev-dojo/SwiftUITextFieldWithDecimalValueTypeApp) and uploaded a minimal project example.

Comment: As @Asad already mentioned, data binding works in Xcode 13 beta 2. However, it does no longer work in any subsequent versions. I have checked this in beta 3 (13A5192j) and beta 4 (13A5201i).


Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Checked the GitHub repo my best bet yet is to put a breakpoint on line 48 `value: $model.decimalQuantity` and check wether the value changes or not. Meanwhile I'll update the beta and look for a solution.

Comment: I have set a property observer on the Decimal property. The original value (5.34) is set again and again. I could not debug into the NumberFormatter. The code part seems to be already closed source.

Comment: It seems evident that Bindings of type Decimal do not respond to any update in value. (If I put a Breakpoint in Xcode 13 beta 2 on Line 48 the breakpoint is triggered on every update of the TextField) You need to file a bug report with Apple. Sorry I couldn't be of much help.

Comment: I will file a bug report with Apple. If Apple suggests a solution, I will post it here. Thank you for your efforts, @Asad. I appreciate your support!

Comment: @Brad, did you ever get this working? I got something similar, so I came here to see the same behaviour.

Comment: @iPadawan, I reported the problem to Apple and followed up several times but never received a reply. Unfortunately, I can't offer you a solution.

Comment: May be a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564332/swiftui-textfield-with-formatter-broken-when-built-with-xcode-13-3

Try a Textfield using `format:` instead of `formatter:`