# SwiftUI TextField with formatter broken when built with Xcode 13.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

It looks like Xcode 13.3 broke the TextField with formatter. In example below the Text should show the value entered in the TextField, which works fine when built with Xcode 13.2.1 (downgraded again to test) but with Xcode 13.3 the TextField does not update its binding value.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var value: Float?

    let decimalFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("some float", value: $value, formatter: decimalFormatter)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            Text("Value: \(value != nil ? String(value!) : "nil")")
        }
    }
    
}
```

- is my code somehow flawed because it stopped working with Xcode 13.3 or is this a bug with Xcode 13.3?
- any idea how to fix my code or workaround that bug in Xcode 13.3? - my current workaround is a downgrade to Xcode 13.2.1

Comment: if `value` is non optional it works ...(just an observation, not a solution)

Comment: good catch! As it seems to be a problem with the optional, then this sounds like a bug to me - filed it to Apple with Feedback Assistant

Comment: There seems that the TexField you want to use does not exist. “formatter” is only valid for non optional.

Comment: Seems Apple documentation is a bit inaccurate there as https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(value:formatter:prompt:label:) mentions "Creates a text field that applies a formatter to a bound optional value, with a label generated from a view builder." although the bound value in the signature is not an optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a different API that does what I expected with optionals: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:format:prompt:)-6ug7k

```
TextField("some float", value: $value, format: FloatingPointFormatStyle.number)
```

Although this does not explain why it previously worked with a Formatter and stopped working with Xcode 13.3, at least this API seems to be specific for optional values.

Limiting fraction digits to 3 also works, it just is not applied instantly during editing but afterwards on focus change.

```
TextField("some float", value: $value, format: FloatingPointFormatStyle.number
.precision(NumberFormatStyleConfiguration.Precision.fractionLength(0...3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Corrected code sample, using the method from [@harp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71578902/354876). This only works on iOS 15+.

```swift
TextField("some float",
           value: $value,
           format: .currency(code: "USD"))
   .onChange(of: value) { newValue in
           print ("value is \(newValue)")
       }
```

Another example of a `format`. Here using one of the Instance Methods from the [Apple docs on FloatingPointFormatStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/floatingpointformatstyle):

```swift
TextField("some float",
           value: $value,
           format: FloatingPointFormatStyle().decimalSeparator(strategy: .automatic))
```

More info on this method is in the [Apple docs for TextField.init(_:value:format:prompt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:format:prompt:)-6ug7k)

Comment: One would think this should work. Alas: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698767 - not for all currencies :/